# How to use onnxruntime parallel with flask?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, onnx, onnxruntime

Created a server that want to run a session of onnxruntime parallel.

First question, will be used multi-threads or multi-processings?

Try to use multi-threads, `app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port='12345', threaded=True)`.
When run 3 threads that the GPU's memory less than 8G, the program can run. But when run 4 threads that the GPU's memory will be greater than 8G, the program have error: `onnxruntime::CudaCall CUBLAS failure 3: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED.`

I know that the problem is leaky of GPU's memory. But I hope that the program don't run crash. So I try to limit the number of threads, and set `intra_op_num_threads = 2` or `inter_op_num_threads = 2` or `os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "2"`, but don't work.
Try to `'gpu_mem_limit'`, don't work either.

```
import onnxruntime as rt
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

sess = rt.InferenceSession(model_XXX, providers=['CUDAExecutionProvider'])

@app.route('/algorithm', methods=['POST'])
def parser():
    prediction = sess.run(...)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port='12345', threaded=True)
```

My understanding is that the Flask HTTP server maybe use different sess for each call.
How can make each call use the same session of onnxruntime?

System information

- OS Platform and Distribution: Windows10
- ONNX Runtime version: 1.8
- Python version: python 3.7
- GPU model and memory: RTX3070 - 8G

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/11156

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney That is my issue, no solution

Comment: I understand, it's a known issue, currently without a solution. It was posted by [ONNX Runtime team at Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19028422/onnx-runtime-team-at-microsoft), but deleted as a link-only answer.